# Can't RDP to Azure VM after altering, then reverting, IP Rules

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

So I just got my first VM on Azure.  With all default settings, I RDP'd to it just fine.  I then proceeded to break everything, presumably.

First, I altered the `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber` from 3389 to xxxxx

Second, I altered the Inbound Firewall Rules (Remote Desktop Inbound) to have a Scope "Remote IP Address" of my office IP Address.

Everything still worked fine.  I assume that, after saving my changes, it would have kicked me if something was wrong.  Just to kick myself in the face, I restarted the machine.

I now can't RDP to the machine.

With PowerShell, I checked the:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName '*Remote Desktop*' | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter
```

It had my public IP Address.

I ATTEMPTED to check:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber"
```

But since the Azure PowerShell runs in 64-bit mode, it doesn't recognize that 32-bit key (That's what I assume).

**HOWEVER**, Azure has some "Reset to Default" type pre-built PowerShell scripts to reset RDP.  After selecting one, it said "`PortNumber: xxxxx`", confirming that it was what I suspected... but then it said it was reset to 3389.  I did `RDPSetings`, `SetRDPPort` back to 3389, and `ResetRDPCert`, which helped reset all the settings... But might that have exacerbated the issue?  Hopefully not.  I also attempted to `Redeploy`, which did not solve the issue.

I also ran my own `Set-NetFirewallRule` back to `Any`, and now the `Get-NetFirewallRule` once again says "any".

So, after using the Azure-Provided RDP Resets, and confirming that the settings are back to default using PowerShell... I still can't get in.  Even when I download the RDP file from the `Overview` page.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's the weekend and most of this ticket's time were overnight hours in the US.  But I'll add my own answer for two reasons:

1. Even if somebody proposed an answer now, I couldn't test it (for reasons obvious in my answer below)
2. I solved my issue, though not in a happy way.

**Answer**

I Deleted my VM and Recreated a new one.  Short but Sweet.  This wasn't as horrible as some situations where the VM had hours and days put into configuration and installations.  It was a new VM, so no biggie.

Answer (score 0):

You solved your problem but just in case you have the same problem in the future, you can use the Run command feature inside the portal, and use the **SetRDPPort** and **RDPSettings** commands

SetRDPPort
[image]

RDPSettings
[image]

Comment: As I mentioned, that Registry key was not accessible by the PowerShell Runner on Azure.  Other posts mention that it is because that key is a 32 bit key, so the 64 bit PowerShell runner couldn't find it.  I couldn't find out how to enter 32 bit mode myself.  But also as I mentioned, When I ran one of the provided Reset options, I noticed it said that key WAS changed back to the correct value.  Lastly, I can't read some of your stuff.  The images are cropped.  You should never post images where you could post searchable text.

Comment: I was facing exactly the same problem with you, and  I solved it with by running these commands via the Azure Portal. Also, I opened ticket to Microsoft Support and they gave me the same instructions.As for the images there are not cropped I can see them. Do you want me write the powershell scripts to text?